# Call two different components of react js on same html page

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react.js by myself, so you may find this question a silly one. But, I want to learn concepts.

**home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AppStyle extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var myStyle = {
            fontSize: 100,
            color: '#FF0000'
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style = {myStyle}>Header Style</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppStyle />, document.getElementById('style'));
export default AppStyle;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var i = 1;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <h2>Content</h2>
                <p data-myattribute = "somevalue">This is the content!!!</p>
                <h1>{1+1}</h1>
                <h1>{i === 1 ? 'True' : 'False'}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default App;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Learn React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <div id="style"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my **index.html**, I have placed two divs, which are calling two different components, but the only first component is loaded on the page. Is there any way to call both of them? And if not then why?

Comment: why not just enclose both of the components inside a component and render it once. ?

Comment: @AneesIjaz Kindly share a link, how do we do that? Just to mention I just started learning today itself. Not have much idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern.

**home.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class AppStyle extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var myStyle = {
            fontSize: 100,
            color: '#FF0000'
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 style = {myStyle}>Header Style</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AppStyle;
```

***index.js***

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from './home';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var i = 1;
        return (
           <>
                <div>
                    <h1>Header</h1>
                    <h2>Content</h2>
                    <p data-myattribute = "somevalue">This is the content!!!</p>
                    <h1>{1+1}</h1>
                    <h1>{i === 1 ? 'True' : 'False'}</h1>
                </div>
                <Home />
           </>

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


export default App;    // not necessary since you are rendering already...
```

you can also create a seperate component for the code

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Learn React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is importing and rendering `Home`. If you *really wanted* to render into *two separate* elements on the same page, then import `Home` into `index.js` and then you can render both.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import AppStyle from './home';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var i = 1;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <h2>Content</h2>
                <p data-myattribute = "somevalue">This is the content!!!</p>
                <h1>{1+1}</h1>
                <h1>{i === 1 ? 'True' : 'False'}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<AppStyle />, document.getElementById('style'));
```

[image: Edit frosty-currying-wd76q]

As others have pointed out though, the normal pattern is to only render a single react application per page.

Comment: First of all, thank for your prompt response. When I am implementing this, I am getting "target container is not a DOM element".

Comment: @HarshSharma Just ensure what you name the import, i.e. `import Home from "./home";` or `import AppStyle from "./home";` is how you try to render it, i.e. `<Home />` or `<AppStyle />`. Updated answer to look more like your work.

Comment: I am using ```'Home'```, which is ```import Home from "./home";``` and ```ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById('style'));```